# Getting a Windows image onto a flash drive to boot from using an old BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, udf

I've got an old laptop (Thinkpad T60, 32 bit, 7 years old) running Linux Mint, on which I'd like to install Windows as well. However, I can't get it to boot from the flash drive containing the Windows installation image:

- After writing the Windows installation image to the flash drive (`dd if=win.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M`), it is being displayed as a *UDF device*. GParted is not able to read any information (*"Warning: unrecognised disk label"*), but contents can be accessed after mounting. When restarting the computer with the flash drive connected, it is not being recognized as bootable device at all.
- When writing [another image](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=219) to the same flash drive using the same method, booting from it works fine.
- After formatting the flash drive as a single FAT32 partition and copying the Windows image's file contents to it, the device seems to be booted from, but complains about not being bootable (*"Please insert a bootable floppy disk"*). Doesn't look like GRUB, might be BIOS or Windows.

How could I receive a flash drive with the Windows image written to it, from which my (maybe old?) BIOS is able to boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the MBR, which is missing from the DVD ISO image. Following the instructions given in [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/167060/233853), I was able to create a bootable flash drive.